# Can't access Windows, deleted boot file

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

- I was using windows 10
- I wanted dual boot ubuntu
- I used a crappy software to clean startup pc
- I made dual boot
- Ubuntu is fine
- Can't boot in windows
- Tried a lot of 1000 ways to access it, even with software like disk repair and rescatux
- System says windows partition is corrupted
- From ubuntu i can access all windows files with file explorer, but i can't use desktop data that is where there are my important files, since it goes through onedrive
- Commands don't detect windows instalation

Any hint ?

Comment: Welcome to AU. You need to provide more information to help us to help you. How exactly did you set up the dual boot? Please describe all the steps you took - the details probably matter a lot. What happens when you try to boot into Windows? Do you get to the Grub menu, or does it boot directly into Ubuntu? I would strongly advise backing up anything you can still access before doing any other attempts to resolve it - you may find data currently available is irrecoverable after further attempts to access it.

Comment: On a 1TB disk i had a partition with 800GB, in that partition i used 250 gb to install ubuntu by a bootable usb. After install ubuntu I had on grub windows and ubuntu, but when i booted into windows it appeared to choose keyboard layout and i followed a 1000 of youtube video with bootsec and bootrec but I wasn't able to go there, now I have indows in my grub but if i click it just keeps going to grub. the windows i have is 10, i saw that if you have a previous windows 10 installation you can reeinstall with usb and keep files and apps, is it true ?    Thank you @Will

Comment: As for reinstalling Windows and keeping previous apps, that's a question for a different forum like Superuser. We can only answer questions about Ubuntu here.

Comment: Thank you Mr @mchid

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to re-run the following command to properly detect Windows now that you rebuilt the Windows bootloader:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update your grub menu.

Comment: Problem persists, probably this is the solution for majority of times but not in this case